# How to create an Ordering[T] from List[T] in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose that I have a the following list

```
val preferences: List[T] = List(t1, t2, t3)
```

For my application the order in which the elements are inserted into `preferences` implies the order in which the elements are preferred (i.e., the most preferred element in `Preferences[T]` is `t1`, the least preferred is `t3`, and `t2` is preferred to `t3` but not `t1`. Elements of `T` not included in `preferences`, say `t4` and `t5`, would be less preferred than `t3` but would be considered equal to one another.

Is there some way to derive an `Ordering[T]` instance based on the insertion order of `List[T]`?

Comment: Well, you defined ordering not on `T` but on the three elements from `T`.

Comment: Good point! I will add some edits accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement custom `Ordering`s with methods on `Ordering` companion object. For example to order by `List`, you have to compare indexes of the elements in this list:

```
def listBasedOrdering[T](list: List[T]): Ordering[T] = {
  Ordering.by[T, Int] { t =>
    val index = list.indexOf(t)
    if (index == -1) list.size else index
  }
}
```

This should work well enough if the `List` is small. But the `indexOf` operation uses linear time, so for larger lists you may want to convert it to a `Map` beforehand:

```
def listBasedOrdering[T](list: List[T]): Ordering[T] = {
  val map = list.zipWithIndex.toMap.withDefaultValue(list.size)
  Ordering.by[T, Int](map)
}
```

And here is a small test:

```
scala> implicit val ord = listBasedOrdering(List("t1", "t2", "t3"))
ord: Ordering[String] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@95cecc5

scala> List("t5", "t3", "t2", "t1", "t0").sorted
res0: List[String] = List(t1, t2, t3, t5, t0)
```